# Парсер по данным

Tags: python, pandas

Имеется следующая таблица

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'id' : ['12', '13', '14'],
        'object' : ['[[[""], [""], [""]]]', '[[["13.21"], ["10.11"], ["11.01"]]]', '[[["3.1"], ["5.1"], ["7.1"]]]']}
data = pd.DataFrame(data)
data
```

Необходимо для каждого id вытащить из столбика object цифры или None.

Ожидаемый результат:

```
data = {'id' : ['12', '13', '14'],
        'ans1' : [None, 13.21, 3.1],
        'ans2' : [None, 10.11, 5.1],
        'ans3' : [None, 11.01, 7.1]}
data = pd.DataFrame(data)
data
```

Спасибо!

Comment: что значит `"вытащить из столбика object цифры"`? Приведите в вопросе результат, который вы хотите получить

Comment: для каждого id создать три переменные, которые будут являться числами из столбика object

Comment: @Panda все равно не понятно. приведите в вопросе желаемый результат.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
res = (data
       .join(data
             .pop("object")
             .str.extractall(r'"(\d+(?:\.\d+))?"')
             [0]
             .unstack()))
```

результат:

```
In [125]: res
Out[125]:
   id      0      1      2
0  12    NaN    NaN    NaN
1  13  13.21  10.11  11.01
2  14    3.1    5.1    7.1
```